# How can I download an earlier version of an app to my macOS on the App Store?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applications, mac-appstore

I’m using an app that I have download from the App Store on my Mac OS. After updating it to it’s latest version recently, it doesn’t seem to have worked very well on my MacBook.

An earlier version worked perfectly well and I want to download and install that particular version back. But I can’t seem to download an older version on App Store. The download button in AppStore only allows me to get the latest version.

Is there anyway I can download an older version of an app on App Store? Otherwise, how else can I do that if it’s not through App Store?

Comment: Have you tried your TimeMachine backup? I have successfully restored apps that changed in unwanted ways this way.

Comment: @MichaelR Sadly, I didn’t have TimeMachine enabled. :(

Comment: :-( There is another convoluted mechanism, but may not be worth the effort. Install an older version of MacOS, and then download from the App store (which should download the latest version available for that platform). This assumes the app developer stops support for older systems fairly quickly. So it will depend on the App if this yields anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no option to download older versions of apps on the Mac App Store.

Depending on the app in question, you might be able to find an older version of said app on the vendor's web site or on downloads sites in general.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s a paid app and they don’t put downloads up on their site. I paid for it on App Store and it seems like I could only download from there. :(

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer?

Comment: Not yet. Perhaps that’s the only way for now.

Answer (score 6):

You can't download **specific** old versions of an app from the App Store.  Read on for various options that might work to get an older version.

## Get older version from a TimeMachine backup

If you have Time Machine backups, maybe you can find an older version of the app in a backup to restore.

## Download directly from the developer

Old versions may or may not directly be available for download directly from the developer. Free, open-source, and paid apps that offer non-App Store sales are more likely to provide older versions for download.  Check their website or git repositories for information about availability of releases for download.

## Build it yourself from source

If it is open source but no pre-built releases are available, you can try to build it yourself and select specific source commits/tags to build at in order to build specific versions.  You will likely lose code signing in this case, but gives you most control if you are comfortable working in terminal and have time to learn how to get an open source app to build.

## If you have previously installed from App Store, you can get last compatible version from "my purchases" (includes free apps) area

If you need an old version because you are running an older version of macOS and the app requires a newer version, you can install the last compatible version by going to **App Store > your user > Purchases** and reinstalling from there.

[image: Screenshot of an App Store message asking 'Download an older version of WireGuard?']

## If you have NOT previously installed from App Store

If you have never installed the app before, you will need to find a computer running a newer version of macOS, sign in to the App Store there, and install the latest version of the app.  Then you can return to your older macOS computer, and install the older version of the app from your purchases area (see previous section).

If you don't have access to a newer macOS or aren't ready to upgrade, you can install a newer version of macOS in VirtualBox.

## Getting older app from App Store on newer macos

Of course, you can go the other way if you are on a newer macOS and want an older app version.  Install an older macOS in a VM, and install the app through the App Store there (you will get the latest compatible version for that OS, not a specific version).  Then copy that app to your newer macOS.  However, this only works if the developers have cut off support for older versions of macOS at certain releases and those cutoff point app versions may or may not contain the features/bugs/issues you want or don't want.

## Avoid the problem in the first place

The best bet to avoid this issue in the future is to make sure you have a huge Time Machine volume with regular backups so you can roll back any app updates you hate.

## Parting thoughts...

Apple wants everyone on their newest OS as soon as possible to keep from having to support/patch too many old OSes.  However, if like me you have an old Mac that has lots of hardware life left but doesn't get OS updates anymore...then you have to resort to workarounds to keep it from becoming electronic waste.

Same thing for app developers.  They don't want to have to support multiple versions of an app because that means any bugs or security issues have to be patched on multiple forks of their code base and more releases have to be built and more AppStore approvals have to be done with each release.  If apps were always improving, this would be fine...but oftentimes bugs or UX issues are introduced when a previous version was stable enough...and as long as you don't expect support from Apple or the developer and aren't worried about security issues not being patched...it should be fine to run old versions.

Comment: FYI, I have quoted your 4th paragraph in an answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469430/how-to-upgrade-an-apple-software-with-app-store

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I decided to re-purchase the app and just get the new version. But when I finally approved the purchase, the AppStore gave me a notification that it wouldn't charge me because it detected that I owned an older version of the same app.

This was for the app Moom purchased on the AppStore.